# How I can define the IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH in delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

I'm working with the  [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and I need pass the `IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH` value to that function. I can't found any delphi translatation for this constant, just i found this C++ definition.

```
# define IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH  CTL_CODE(IOCTL_SCSI_BASE, 0x040B, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
```

but i have problems to translate that value to delphi using the `CTL_CODE` macro. the question is how i can define the IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH in delphi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CTL_CODE macro is defined as

```
#define CTL_CODE(DeviceType, Function, Method, Access) (
  ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method)
)
```

So the delphi equivalent of the `IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH` const is something like this

```
uses
  Windows;

const
//#define IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH  CTL_CODE(IOCTL_SCSI_BASE, 0x040B, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
IOCTL_SCSI_BASE       = FILE_DEVICE_CONTROLLER;
IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH= (IOCTL_SCSI_BASE shl 16) or ((FILE_READ_ACCESS or FILE_WRITE_ACCESS) shl 14) or ($040B shl 2) or (METHOD_BUFFERED);
```

Note : Unfortunally delphi doesn't supports macros, but you can create a function

```
function CTL_CODE(DeviceType, _Function, Method, Access: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := (DeviceType shl 16) or (Access Shl 14) or (_Function shl 2) or (Method);
end;
```

and get the value in run-time in this way

```
Flag:=CTL_CODE(IOCTL_SCSI_BASE, $040B , METHOD_BUFFERED, (FILE_READ_ACCESS or FILE_WRITE_ACCESS));
```

Comment: But can you even use this stuff in Delphi ? Isn't that driver specific ? (+1)

Comment: Yes, you can use this from delphi, for example to retieve S.M.A.R.T. data of the hdd.

Answer (score 1):

It has a value of `$0004d02c`. I obtained this with the following C program.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Ntddscsi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%.8x", IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH);
    return 0;
}
```

I personally feel that it's safer to use the actual Windows header files than to attempt translation, but perhaps that's just because I don't know enough about C!